# How to get product details when FPC is on magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

It looks like, when Full Page Cache (FPC) is enabled, catalog_controller_product_view event won't get dispatched for every product page views.

there is one event controller_front_send_response_before which will fired for actions. But I couldn't get product information within this observer. Any lead will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Magento versions you've mentioned dont have built in FPC, so I guess you are using a third party module, the version of which may impact this answer.

For Magento Enterprise FPC and (I believe) Lesti FPC you can hook in to this event;

```
controller_action_predispatch
```

This is the only event we found would fire 100% of the time with EE FPC enabled.

Using this you can check for the front controller action before running any custom script, for example, in your module config;

```
....
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <mynamespace_mymodule>
                    <class>mynamespace_mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>firewithfpc</method>
                </mynamespace_mymodule>
            </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Then in your observer;

```
public function firewithfpc($event) {

$action = $event->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
   if($action instanceof Mage_Catalog_ProductController) {

      // DO SOMETHING HERE FOR PRODUCT VIEW    

   }

}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for reply. Is it okay to do it in backend considering it might add load to the server? Or is it better to add it front end when user views some product

Comment: if you are trying to fire some script when a product is viewed on the frontend, then <frontend> is the way to go.  The amount of server overhead is virtually zero.  We used this method for a custom geoiP location module we built, the performance impact was undetectable.

Comment: hi, if this worked for you can you accept it as the answer. thanks

Comment: this didn't work for me. I tried if(Mage::registry('current_product'))[}. this worked for me

Comment: @HariKrishnan, please add your solution to the question as an answer